# c# client-server using UDP Connection

Tags: c#

I am trying to make client Server appilcation in c#. On the Client side i write hello message to Server and Server receives the message.
once the Server receive the message, it should send back client a messsage indicating that message has been received. Basically an acknowledment.
My Problem is that Client doesn´t receive the message form Server.
On down is my code for both Client and Server.

**Client part:**

```
string x = "192.168.1.4";
IPAddress add = IPAddress.Parse(x);
IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(add, 2789);

using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from client");
    client.Send(data, data.Length, point); 

    string serverResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.Receive(ref point));

    Console.WriteLine("Messahe received from server:"+ serverResponse);
}
```

**Server part:**

```
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2789);
        Console.WriteLine("Client address is:" + groupEP.Address.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Client port is:" + groupEP.Port.ToString()); 

        byte[]data = new byte[1024];
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(2789);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
        byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
        Console.WriteLine("Received Data:"+ Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));

        //sending acknoledgment
        string welcome = "Hello how are you from server?";
        byte[]d1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
        listener.Send(d1, d1.Length, groupEP);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent to client back as acknowledgment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code and it work so your issue is an "outside" problem such as :

- A firewall is blocking something (either the connection or the server binding).

  - Because the ip in your sample is a lan ip it is probably the built-in firewall from Windows (or a third-party firewall).
    Try to disable your firewall, [here is how to disable the built-in firewall of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-firewall-on-off#turn-windows-firewall-on-off=windows-7).
- You test the client on a different computer than the server and use the wrong ip.
  If you do test on the same machine you may use the special ip 127.0.0.1 (aka the DNS localhost). 127.0.0.1 always refer to the computer that is running the code. Using this special ip may avoid you trouble in future if your local ip does changes.

And by the way, in your server code you should reuse the "listener" field for each interation of while() such as in

```
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2789);
        Console.WriteLine("Client address is:" + groupEP.Address.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Client port is:" + groupEP.Port.ToString());

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(2789);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
            byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Data:" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));

            //sending acknoledgment
            string welcome = "Hello how are you from server?";
            byte[] d1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
            listener.Send(d1, d1.Length, groupEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent to client back as acknowledgment");

        }
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. I tried the steps you mentioned but ist still the same Problem.